# HTML5 video (HD) cannot loop gapless in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

In Chrome, looping HTML5 video with the `loop` attribute creates a gap after each loop if the video is high definition. See this fiddle for a comparison between SD and HD video:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pczx6/1/

Note the freeze at the end of each loop (the video is only 10 seconds).

Is there a way to eliminate the gap?

In Safari, there is no gap. In Firefox, there is one though I only tested it with an MP4 piped through an .swf with video.js – I guess this does not count as HTML5 video.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ist that Vimeo does a 302 Redirect for the video to a temporary URL. This 302 redirect causes Chrome not to cache the video, according to somebody from the Chromium team. See his response in the bug report I filed: [Chromium Issue 393190: HD HTML5 video does not loop seamlessly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393190)

This explains Chrome's behaviour. However, it does not solve the problem. The URL Vimeo redirects to is temporary. I have no way to know what the URL will be an hour or a day from now, so I cannot put it in the `src=` attribute of my `<video>` element.